# Can I store a typename?

Tags: c++

Here is my example class for accessing memory:

```
class memory {
  public:
    memory();

    template <typename T>
    T get(int index);
    template <typename T>
    void set(int index, T value);
};
```

And here I use it:

```
int main(){
  memory mem;

  float f = mem.get<float>(0);
  char* str = mem.get<char*>(1);

  mem.set<float>(0, 25);  // int passed, upgraded to float

  return 0;
}
```

And I'd like to use it this way:

```
int main(){
  memory<float, char*> mem;  // typenames defined only once. Must accept a variable number of template arguments

  float f = mem.get(0);
  char* str = mem.get(1);

  mem.set(0, 25);  // int passed, upgraded to float

  return 0;
}
```

How can I implement this? Is it even possible?

Comment: You could use `typeid` maybe.

Comment: You seem to be trying to reinvent [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

Comment: Why are you doing this? What is the problem you are attempting to solve with this class? Are you sure you won't be breaking [the strict aliasing rule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)?

Comment: By the way, with your original class as you show, you don't have to provide the type to `set`, the compiler will be able to deduce it. So you can do just `mem.set(0, 2.5f)`

Comment: I have to make sure the right type is passed for a compiler to deduce it properly. And I am not entirely happy about that

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want `std::tuple` or `hana::tuple`. It's entirely possible to change you class so that you don't need to send the type each time.

However, you will still need to pass something as a template parameter. Usually, the index of the variable or the index of the type is enough.

The `tuple` class from the standard library does it like this:

```
std::tuple<int, std::string> tup;

std::get<0>(tup) = 5; // assign the int
std::get<1>(tup) = "test"; // assign the string
```

Boost hana skies it in a similar way, but uses `operator[]`:

```
hana::tuple<int, std::string> tup;

tup[0_c] = 5; // assign the int
tup[1_c] = "test"; // assign the string
```

The `_c` is a user provided literal that transform the int into an integral constant, so the value can be used at compile time.

---

So how you'd do it?

Simply change your int parameter to a template parameter:

```
int main() {
  memory<float, char*> mem;

  float f = mem.get<0>();
  char* str = mem.get<1>();

  mem.set<0>(25);  // int passed, upgraded to float

  return 0;
}
```

And then, to infer what the type is according to the index, use something like this:

```
template<std::size_t, typename>
struct memory_element; // no basic case

// In this case, we pass a number and a memory class
// We extend the case were the index is decremented, and we remove the first type.
template<std::size_t index, typename Head, typename... Tail>
struct memory_element<index, memory<Head, Tail...> : memory_element<index - 1, memory<Tail...>> {};

// Case where we get to 0
template<typename T, typename... Rest>
struct memory_element<0, memory<T, Rest...>> {
    using type = T;
};

// Alias for ease of use
template<std::size_t I, typename M>
using memory_element_t = typename memory_element<I, M>::type;
```

You can the use it like this:

```
int main () {
    // T1 is int
    using T1 = memory_element_t<0, memory<int, float>>;

    // T2 is float
    using T2 = memory_element_t<1, memory<int, float>>;
}
```